# Can I use glasses-cleaning leather to make a strop?

Tags: hand-tools, sharpening

I am having difficulties finding some scrap piece of leather in order to make myself a strop in order to aid the sharpening process for my plane blades and chisels.

[image]

I was thinking to use this kind of (hopefully) genuine leather and I am not sure if it is a good idea. I mean the oxide-loaded strop:

[image]

Is it feasible?

Comment: Not the ideal material, no. Even thought the Q wasn't really about this I covered a lot of the relevant territory in a previous Answer, [here](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/2085/how-can-i-tell-if-leather-is-vegetable-tanned/2087#2087).

Comment: Check the Good Will or Salvation Army for an old, wide belt.

Comment: Or check your local craft or artisan meetups. Leather workers often have suitable scraps of heavy leather you can load up with your levels of compound.

Comment: Just for reference this kind of leather is know as "chamois".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chamois_leather .  It is probably the softest kind of leather around, which is the exact opposite of what you want for a strop.  "Horse butt" leather is widely regarded as the best leather for strops due to how hard it is.

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232, horse butt or something similar is only really of importance for those intending to strop on the bare leather.

Comment: Another good option for stropping is loading green buffing compound on MDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question at hand, no. This is not appropriate material for stropping tool edges.

Let's aggregate the answers that popped up in comments:

- Check [this Answer](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/2085/how-can-i-tell-if-leather-is-vegetable-tanned/2087#2087) for hints
- Look around for a local leatherworker to acquire scraps of heavier hide suitable for turning into a strop
- Check charity shops for an old "full grain" leather belt (i.e., not compressed or bonded leather)

Comment: "Full Grain Leather" is what he needs. I think the compressed kind is called "Bonded Leather."

Comment: @Ring, important take-home message from the previous Answer is that OP doesn't need leather at all if he's intending on using compound.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the prior answer and comments and thought I would add another suggestion to try.  A very flat smooth piece of wood such as a finish grade plywood makes a great strop or base for a leather strop.
I have piece of plywood that I applied stropping compound to and it works great.  As a woodworker it easy to make a strop like this of any size or shape you like with or without a handle.  And you are pretty much guaranteed to have the material laying in your scrap bin right now.

Comment: Good point. In fact, for some of my larger blades, a softer wood "strop" would make more sense. I'm going to try it when I get around to putting a new edge on my block plane and repairing an unfortunate paring chisel that got really rust damaged.